# Sudden issue with data display (using Google Maps) on Chromium

Tags: raspbian, chromium

I'm subscribed to a weather website which shows live data using Google Maps, with an info box appearing if you hover over a data point.

I have a Pi (Raspbian 8) set up to access this via Chromium and capture certain info on a regular basis. This worked fine for two years but suddenly stopped.

The issue is the map's now totally blank when using Chromium. Attached are two screenshots - one showing how it now looks on the Pi and one showing how it should look (via Windows laptop).

I've tried:

- totally uninstalling and reinstalling Chromium
- using another browser
  (same happens)
- using a backup image on the same SD card (same happens despite the backup being taken over a year ago)
- doing 'apt-get update'

However, it **does** still work when I tried using another Pi.

Anyone have any ideas what's wrong? I'm baffled considering it works on another Pi, but an earlier version of the same image on the same Pi doesn't work.

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: use DevTools to determine if anything is being *not-found* ... also, please add a clear, answerable question to your post ... `anyone have ideas?` is not a question about a problem

Comment: NEVER use apt-get in interactive mode. You may miss vital prompts. Use apt which is designed for interactive use.